# Browser support for SVG manipulation?

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser

Does anyone know the browser support for using things like stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset?

I'm only asking here because I can't seem to find it anywhere else on the web.

For reference, this pen works perfectly on Chrome and Opera. It applies the wrong fill when complete on Firefox. And on IE it doesn't even show.

http://codepen.io/mildrenben/pen/yydxGY

```
svg {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 800px; 
  stroke-linecap: square;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke: transparent;
  fill: none;
  stroke-dasharray: 3500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 3500;
}

.fil0 {
  animation: black 3s ease-in forwards;
}

.fil1, .fil2 {
  animation: green 3s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes green {
  80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke: $green;
  }
  85% {
    fill: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    fill: $green;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes black {
  80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke: $black;
  }
  85% {
    fill: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    fill: $black;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Browser support for CSS animation of SVG is a work in progress in all UAs. You could do this in SMIL in Firefox and support IE too that way via fakesmile.

Comment: [**Mozilla Developer Network**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) is usually pretty up-to-date. or [**CanIUse.com**](http://caniuse.com/)

Comment: for the ff bug, just replace `fill:none` to `fill:transparent` in `svg {}`